# Does Angular destroy manually created components if there are removed from DOM?

Tags: angular, dom, components, destroy

Does angular destroy component if we add and remove it from DOM manually?

```js
constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private appRef: ApplicationRef,
    private injector: Injector
) {
    // Create component
    const myComponentRef = this.componentFactoryResolver
        .resolveComponentFactory(MyComponent)
        .create(this.injector);
    this.appRef.attachView(myComponentRef.hostView);

    // Subscribe on 'someChange' event of the component
    myComponent.instance.someChange.subscribe(() => {
        // Should be unsubscribed if the component is destroyed
    });

    // Non Angular DOM manipulation
    const myComponentElement = componentRef.hostView.rootNodes[0];
    const containerElement = document.getElementById('container');

    containerElement.appendChild(myComponentElement);
    containerElement.innerHtml = '';
}
```

Some more details, some more details, some more details... StackOverflow is a little bit blunt to understand that the code contains all possible details

Comment: To check that could you try adding a timer which has a console in it in the component which you add and remove. You can check whether its destroyed by looking at the console

Comment: @SebaCherian, I checked it in console. Angular don't destroy dynamic components( Or I do something wrong